# How to capture click between several operations, 3,4,5,6, X, 2?

Tags: java

I'm programming a game of cards in Java and everything is going well, but I've come up with an unforeseen reason why I think I can not think of what to use and I want to know what idea to follow. I go:

My game:
My game consists of 6 players, I am always the Player 1 and the other players the computer, therefore I have done with 6 JLabel in a JFrame, each Jlabel means the card that throws jug1 ... jug6, and in the code I take the order of which player wins the hand with an array of integers equal to [*3*,4,5,6,**1**,2] assuming player 3 was won by hand.

My problem:
Taking the above arrangement as a reference [*3*,4,5,6,**1**,2], it means that in the next hand players [3,4,5,6] must show their card before Player 1, and After Player 1 shows his card, he must show Player 2.

I know how to show the cards of the first four players, but how can I make my program wait for me to click on my selected card and then continue with the last card of Player 2, my main question is how to receive that click Of Player 1 between players, before or after.

Here a fragment:

```
public void Tirar(JLabel [] label_cartas_en_mesa) //director function
        {
            cartas_en_mesa = new Vector<Baraja>();

            for ( int i =0; i < 6; i++ )
            {
                switch( orden_de_tiro [i] )
                {
                    case 1: { Tirar_Jugador1(label_cartas_en_mesa, i); break; }
                    case 2: { Tirar_Jugador2(label_cartas_en_mesa, i); break; }
                    case 3: { Tirar_Jugador3(label_cartas_en_mesa, i); break; }
                    case 4: { Tirar_Jugador4(label_cartas_en_mesa, i); break; }
                    case 5: { Tirar_Jugador5(label_cartas_en_mesa, i); break; }
                    case 6: { Tirar_Jugador6(label_cartas_en_mesa, i); break; }               

                    default:break;
                }            
            }

        }

public void Tirar_Jugador1(JLabel [] label_cartas_en_mesa, int pos)
    {    //decision_jug1 = true when I clicked a card and then break a loop.
        while(decision_jug1==false) //My wrong idea to wait, I think..
        { }

        label_cartas_en_mesa[pos].setIcon( new ImageIcon( Jug1_Barajas.get(pos_baraja_jug1).getImagen() ) );
        cartas_en_mesa.add( Jug1_Barajas.get(pos_baraja_jug1) );
        Jug1_Barajas.remove(pos_baraja_jug1);
        decision_jug1 = false;
    }

    public void Tirar_Jugador2(JLabel [] label_cartas_en_mesa, int pos)
    {
        label_cartas_en_mesa[ pos ].setIcon( new ImageIcon( Jug2_Barajas.get(0).getImagen()));
        cartas_en_mesa.add( Jug2_Barajas.get(0) );
        Jug2_Barajas.remove(0);        
    }

    public void Tirar_Jugador3(JLabel [] label_cartas_en_mesa, int pos)
    {
        label_cartas_en_mesa[ pos ].setIcon( new ImageIcon( Jug3_Barajas.get(0).getImagen()));
        cartas_en_mesa.add( Jug3_Barajas.get(0) );
        Jug3_Barajas.remove(0);        
    }

    public void Tirar_Jugador4(JLabel [] label_cartas_en_mesa, int pos)
    {
        label_cartas_en_mesa[ pos ].setIcon( new ImageIcon( Jug4_Barajas.get(0).getImagen()));
        cartas_en_mesa.add( Jug4_Barajas.get(0) );
        Jug4_Barajas.remove(0);        
    }

    public void Tirar_Jugador5(JLabel [] label_cartas_en_mesa, int pos)
    {
        label_cartas_en_mesa[ pos ].setIcon( new ImageIcon( Jug5_Barajas.get(0).getImagen()));
        cartas_en_mesa.add( Jug5_Barajas.get(0) );
        Jug5_Barajas.remove(0);        
    }

    public void Tirar_Jugador6(JLabel [] label_cartas_en_mesa, int pos)
    {
        label_cartas_en_mesa[ pos ].setIcon( new ImageIcon( Jug6_Barajas.get(0).getImagen()));
        cartas_en_mesa.add( Jug6_Barajas.get(0) );
        Jug6_Barajas.remove(0);        
    }
```

regards,
Alex

Comment: What code have you completed so far? We can't help without a reference point.

Comment: From a design perspective, consider that each `Player` can have a `showCard()` method. For computer players, the `showCard` simply displays the result. For human players, it requires an input. The system is driven by a game loop. See Nystrom, *Game Programming Patterns*.

Comment: Add my fragment, thks

Answer (score 0):

you can have an array of players, all of them including you.
the player may have several members and methods, the 2 methods i want to focus on are `play()` and `isHuman()`, in your Game class? there is a method `playHand(int)` which will control the process:

assume the players array (or list) is

```
//it contains 6 objects, one of them is You.
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
players.add(player1);// add all 6 players...
//make sure when u add human to set isHuman(true)...
```

and we need to have a method that we will call when it's the Human (you) turn in game, assume it's `notifiyHumanPlayer(int)`

we also need a local member (class scope) variable the points to the current player.

```
private int CURRENT_PLAYER = 0;
```

so your code may look like this:

the method that starts the hand (the round)

```
private void playHand(int startingPlayerIndex){
    for(int i=startingPlayerIndex; i<players.size();i++){
        CURRENT_PLAYER = i;

        if(!players.get(i).isHuman()){
            //not human
            notifiyPlayer(i);
            players.get(i).play();
        }else{
            //human
            notifiyPlayer(i);
            //no call to play();...
            break;
        }
    }//for loop

    //when loop ends, all players were done, do what you do at end of each hand...
    calculateHandWinner();
}
```

Shows a simple indicator (arrow) or play some sound...

```
private void notifiyPlayer(int myIndex){
    //it may show an arrow or indeicator on/next player icon, to show which who's playing now
    showTurnIndecator(myIndex);
}
```

when it's your turn, just the `onClick` of any card you have

```
private void humanPlayerOnClick(){
    //this is the onClick() of the human (when human clicks on any of the cards)

    //write the code for drawing a card from human's hand

    // now we need to see if human was last player, or not,
    if(CURRENT_PLAYER+1 >= players.size()){
        //all players were done, do what you do at end of each hand...
        calculateHandWinner();
    }else{
        //still more players after human in the array
        playHand(CURRENT_PLAYER+1); // same loop but it will start from the player next to human.
    }
}


private void calculateHandWinner(){
    //do your logic here ...

    //re arrange players list...

    playHand(0);//start next hand from first player...
}
```

not sure if this will suite your current structure you may take something useful out of it.